# How can I merge 200 CSV files in Python?

Tags: python, csv, merge, concatenation

I here have 200 separate CSV files named from SH (1) to SH (200). I want to merge them into a single CSV file. How can I do it?

Comment: In what way would you merge them? (Concatenate lines, ...)

Comment: How do you want them merged? Each line in a CSV file is a row. So one simple option is to just concatenate all the files together.

Comment: Each file has two columns. I want to merge them into a single file with two columns consecutively.

Comment: @Chuck: Howzabout about taking all the responses in your comments (to the question, and to the answers) and updating your question?

Comment: This question should be named "How to **concat**..." instead of "how to **merge**..."

Answer (score 109, accepted):

As [ghostdog74 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-can-i-merge-200-csv-files-in-python/2512418#2512418), but this time with headers:

```
with open("out.csv", "ab") as fout:
    # First file:
    with open("sh1.csv", "rb") as f:
        fout.writelines(f)

    # Now the rest:
    for num in range(2, 201):
        with open("sh" + str(num) + ".csv", "rb") as f:
            next(f) # Skip the header, portably
            fout.writelines(f)
```

Comment: you can use `f.__next__()` instead if `f.next()` in python3.x.

Comment: Just a note: One can use the `with open` syntax and avoid manually `.close()`ing the files.

Comment: what's the difference between `f.next()` and `f.__next__()`? when I use the former, I got `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: before ```fout.write(line)``` I would do: ```if line[-1] != '\n': line += '\n' ```

Comment: @tsveti_iko: Portably, you'd do `next(f)`, which works on every version of Python from 2.6 onwards.

Comment: @JasonGoal: Python 3 changed the name of the special method for iterators from Py2's `.next` (which was not properly reserved) to `.__next__` (which, thanks to beginning and ending in `__`, can't be reused for other purposes by user code without violating language requirements). The portable approach is to use neither, and just call the top-level function `next` on the iterator, making it `next(f)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the explanation. Nice to meet here at 2022.

Answer (score 79):

You can just use `sed 1d sh*.csv > merged.csv`.

Sometimes you don't even have to use Python!

Comment: On windows, C:\> copy *.csv merged.csv

Comment: Copy the header information from one file: sed -n 1p some_file.csv > merged_file.csv
Copy all but the last line from all other files: sed 1d *.csv >> merged_file.csv

Comment: @blinsay It adds the header in each CSV file to the merged file as well though.

Comment: How do you use this command without copying the header information for each subsequent file after the first one? I seem to be getting the header info popping up repeatedly.

Comment: This is great if you don't need to remove the header!

Comment: To remove the header, do it in a loop: `for f in mydir; do sed 1d $f >> merged.csv; done`

Comment: I accidentally did `sed 1d *.csv > merged.csv` and this ran for while before my computer crashed because of no storage space left! :(

Comment: this command works for me: " sed 1d *.csv >> merged_file.csv" , it shows index.  result file size is 130 MB big. when I merge 10 csv files in another way, size is 14.5 MB. That is why there was storage shortage sometimes. My question: how to eliminate INDEX?

Answer (score 65):

Use [the accepted Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909975/python-list-directory-subdirectory-and-files) to create a list of CSV files that you want to append and then run this code:

```
import pandas as pd

combined_csv = pd.concat( [ pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames ] )
```

And if you want to export it to a single CSV file, use this:

```
combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: @wisty,@Andy, suppose all files have titles for each row - some rows with different titles. No headers for the 2 columns in each file.  How can one merge, such that for each file only a column is added.

Comment: Where does the file get exported to?

Comment: @dirtysocks45, I changed the answer to make this more explicit.

Comment: add sort : combined_csv = pd.concat( [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames ], sort=False)

Comment: for thousands of csv files it takes so much time and a lots of memory!

Answer (score 17):

```
fout=open("out.csv","a")
for num in range(1,201):
    for line in open("sh"+str(num)+".csv"):
         fout.write(line)    
fout.close()
```

Comment: Why the magic number 201? Why isn't it off by one? Is it exclusive? It might be related the question's "200 separate CSV files". An explanation of the code would be in order.

Answer (score 12):

It depends what you mean by "merging"—do they have the same columns?  Do they have headers?  For example, if they all have the same columns, and no headers, simple concatenation is sufficient (open the destination file for writing, loop over the sources opening each for reading, use [shutil.copyfileobj](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#shutil.copyfileobj) from the open-for-reading source into the open-for-writing destination, close the source, keep looping—use the `with` statement to do the closing on your behalf).  If they have the same columns, but also headers, you'll need a `readline` on each source file except the first, after you open it for reading before you copy it into the destination, to skip the headers line.

If the CSV files don't all have the same columns then you need to define in what sense you're "merging" them (like a SQL JOIN? or "horizontally" if they all have the same number of lines? Etc., etc.)—it's hard for us to guess what you mean in that case.

Comment: Each file has two columns with headers. I want to merge them into a single file with two columns consecutively.

Answer (score 12):

I'm just going to throw another code example into the basket:

```
from glob import glob

with open('singleDataFile.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
    for csvFile in glob('*.csv'):
        for line in open(csvFile, 'r'):
            singleFile.write(line)
```

Comment: @Andy I fail to see the difference between stackoverflow reminding me to vote up an answer and me reminding people to share their appreciation (by voting up) if they found my answer useful. I know that this is not Facebook and I'm not a like-hunter..

Comment: It has been [discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63440/186281) [previously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194063/186281), and each time it has been [deemed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167155/comments-asking-for-upvotes-accepts) unacceptable.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the gist of it? The glob thing? What are the advantages and disadvantages? Does it work on Windows? Behavior on case-insensitive and case-sensitive file systems? How is it different from previous answers? (But *** *** ***without*** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: [An answer claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-can-i-merge-200-csv-files-in-python/25889148#25889148) it doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite easy to combine all files in a directory and merge them:

```
import glob
import csv


# Open result file
with open('output.txt', 'wb') as fout:
    wout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')
    interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
    h = True
    for filename in interesting_files:
        print 'Processing', filename
        # Open and process file
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
            if h:
                h = False
            else:
                fin.next() # Skip header
            for line in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=','):
                wout.writerow(line)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the gist of it? E.g., why is it necessary to open the files to get information in them? What is the idea? (But *** *** ***without*** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the in-built [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) library. This solution will work even if some of your CSV files have slightly different column names or headers, unlike the other top-voted answers.

```
import csv
import glob


filenames = [i for i in glob.glob("SH*.csv")]
header_keys = []
merged_rows = []

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        merged_rows.extend(list(reader))
        header_keys.extend([key for key in reader.fieldnames if key not in header_keys])

with open("combined.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header_keys)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(merged_rows)
```

The merged file will contain all possible columns (`header_keys`) that can be found in the files. Any absent columns in a file would be rendered as blank / empty (but preserving rest of the file's data).

Note:

- This won't work if your CSV files have no headers. In that case you can still use the `csv` library, but instead of using `DictReader` & `DictWriter`, you'll have to work with the basic `reader` & `writer`.
- This may run into issues when you are dealing with massive data since the entirety of the content is being store in memory (`merged_rows` list).

Comment: For the writer, `fieldnames=` can be any iterable, so a set or even a dict will do and you can drop the `keys.extend([... if ... not])` list comprehension in favor of `keys.update(reader.fieldnames)`.

Comment: Finally an answer that isn't a code dump!

Answer (score 3):

If the merged CSV is going to be used in Python then just use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) to get a list of the files to pass to [`fileinput.input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) via the `files` argument, then use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module to read it all in one go.

Answer (score 3):

A slight change to [Norfeldt's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-can-i-merge-200-csv-files-in-python/17947216#17947216) as it does not actually work correctly.

It should be as follows...

```
from glob import glob

with open('main.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
    for csv in glob('*.csv'):
        if csv == 'main.csv':
            pass
        else:
            for line in open(csv, 'r'):
                singleFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Re *"does not actually work correctly"*: On what system (incl. versions) and under what conditions (e.g., the set of files) did that not work? Can you be more specific than *"does not actually work correctly"*? In what way did it not work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on Linux or Mac, you can do this.

```
from subprocess import call

script = "cat *.csv > merge.csv"
call(script, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

OR, you could just do

```
cat sh*.csv > merged.csv
```

Comment: This will also copy the header line of the files for each file.

Comment: This is operating system / shell dependent. What is assumed? [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint)?

Answer (score 2):

Over the solution that was [made by Adders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-can-i-merge-200-csv-files-in-python/25889148#25889148) and later on improved [by varun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-can-i-merge-200-csv-files-in-python/27422341#27422341), I implemented some little improvement to leave the whole merged CSV with only the main header:

```
from glob import glob

filename = 'main.csv'

with open(filename, 'a') as singleFile:
    first_csv = True
    for csv in glob('*.csv'):
        if csv == filename:
            pass
        else:
            header = True
            for line in open(csv, 'r'):
                if first_csv and header:
                    singleFile.write(line)
                    first_csv = False
                    header = False
                elif header:
                    header = False
                else:
                    singleFile.write(line)
    singleFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done it by implementing a function that expects an output file and paths of the input files.

The function copies the file content of the first file into the output file and then does the same for the rest of input files, but without the header line.

```
def concat_files_with_header(output_file, *paths):
    for i, path in enumerate(paths):
        with open(path) as input_file:
            if i > 0:
                next(input_file)  # Skip header
            output_file.writelines(input_file)
```

Usage example of the function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    paths = [f"sh{i}.csv" for i in range(1, 201)]
    with open("output.csv", "w") as output_file:
        concat_files_with_header(output_file, *paths)
```

Comment: Thank you. I went through all the solutions here and this one works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could import the *csv* module then loop through all the CSV files reading them into a list. Then write the list back out to disk.

```
import csv

rows = []

for f in (file1, file2, ...):
    reader = csv.reader(open("f", "rb"))

    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row)

writer = csv.writer(open("some.csv", "wb"))
writer.writerows("\n".join(rows))
```

The above is not very robust as it doesn't have any error handling nor does it close any open files.

This should work whether or not the the individual files have one or more rows of CSV data in them. Also I did not run this code, but it should give you an idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can iterate all the files present in the root dir and then you can read each file and use the concat function to concatenate each csv file

```
files = os.listdir(root_dir)
final_data = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
  file_path = os.path.join(root_dir,file)
  df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
  final_data = pd.concat([final_data, df], ignore_index=True)
final_data.to_csv("Final_Data.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

I modified what [wisty said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-can-i-merge-200-csv-files-in-python/2512572#2512572) to be working with Python 3.x, for those of you that have an encoding problem. Also I use the *os* module to avoid hard coding.

```
import os

def merge_all():
    dir = os.chdir('C:\python\data\\')
    fout = open("merged_files.csv", "ab")

    # First file:
    for line in open("file_1.csv", 'rb'):
        fout.write(line)

    # Now the rest:
    list = os.listdir(dir)
    number_files = len(list)
    for num in range(2, number_files):
        f = open("file_" + str(num) + ".csv", 'rb')
        f.__next__()  # Skip the header
        for line in f:
            fout.write(line)
        f.close()  # Not really needed
    fout.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a script:

- Concatenating CSV files named `SH1.csv` to `SH200.csv`
- Keeping the headers

```py
import glob
import re

# Looking for filenames like 'SH1.csv' ... 'SH200.csv'
pattern = re.compile("^SH([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|200).csv$")
file_parts = [name for name in glob.glob('*.csv') if pattern.match(name)]

with open("file_merged.csv","wb") as file_merged:
    for (i, name) in enumerate(file_parts):
        with open(name, "rb") as file_part:
            if i != 0:
                next(file_part) # Skip headers if not the first file
            file_merged.write(file_part.read())
```

Answer (score -1):

Updating [wisty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-can-i-merge-200-csv-files-in-python/2512572#2512572) for Python 3:

```
fout = open("out.csv", "a")
# First file:
for line in open("sh1.csv"):
    fout.write(line)

# Now the rest:
for num in range(2, 201):
    f = open("sh" + str(num) + ".csv")
    next(f) # Skip the header
    for line in f:
         fout.write(line)
    f.close() # Not really needed
fout.close()
```

Comment: What is the magic number "2"? To compensate because the first answer using the magic number 201 was off by one? Or for some other reason? An explanation of the code and the reason for choices in it would be in order.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have two CSV files like these:

#### File *csv1.csv*

```
id,name
1,Armin
2,Sven
```

#### File *csv2.csv*

```
id,place,year
1,Reykjavik,2017
2,Amsterdam,2018
3,Berlin,2019
```

And you want the result to be like this (file *csv3.csv*):

```
id,name,place,year
1,Armin,Reykjavik,2017
2,Sven,Amsterdam,2018
3,,Berlin,2019
```

Then you can use the following snippet to do that:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# The file names
f1 = "csv1.csv"
f2 = "csv2.csv"
out_f = "csv3.csv"

# Read the files
df1 = pd.read_csv(f1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(f2)

# Get the keys
keys1 = list(df1)
keys2 = list(df2)

# Merge both files
for idx, row in df2.iterrows():
    data = df1[df1['id'] == row['id']]

    # If row with such id does not exist, add the whole row
    if data.empty:
        next_idx = len(df1)
        for key in keys2:
            df1.at[next_idx, key] = df2.at[idx, key]

    # If row with such id exists, add only the missing keys with their values
    else:
        i = int(data.index[0])
        for key in keys2:
            if key not in keys1:
                df1.at[i, key] = df2.at[idx, key]

# Save the merged files
df1.to_csv(out_f, index=False, encoding='utf-8', quotechar="", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

With the help of a loop, you can achieve the same result for multiple files as it is in your case (200 CSV files).

Answer (score -1):

If the files aren't numbered in order, take the hassle-free approach below:

Python 3.6 on a Windows machine:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

interesting_files = glob("C:/temp/*.csv") # It grabs all the csv files from
                                          # the directory you mention here

df_list = []
for filename in sorted(interesting_files):

df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
full_df = pd.concat(df_list)

# Save the final file in same/different directory:
full_df.to_csv("C:/temp/merged_pandas.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: This trivially doesn't work (indentation - `IndentationError: expected an indented block`). Where did you copy it from?

Answer (score -1):

An easy-to-use function:

```
def csv_merge(destination_path, *source_paths):
'''
Merges all csv files on source_paths to destination_path.
:param destination_path: Path of a single csv file, doesn't need to exist
:param source_paths: Paths of csv files to be merged into, needs to exist
:return: None
'''
with open(destination_path,"a") as dest_file:
    with open(source_paths[0]) as src_file:
        for src_line in src_file.read():
            dest_file.write(src_line)
    source_paths.pop(0)
    for i in range(len(source_paths)):
        with open(source_paths[i]) as src_file:
            src_file.next()
            for src_line in src_file:
                 dest_file.write(src_line)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv("e:\\data science\\kaggle assign\\monthly sales\\Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master\\SalesAnalysis\\Sales_Data\\Sales_April_2019.csv")
files = [file for file in  os.listdir("e:\\data science\\kaggle assign\\monthly sales\\Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master\\SalesAnalysis\\Sales_Data")
for file in files:
    print(file)

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv("e:\\data science\\kaggle assign\\monthly sales\\Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master\\SalesAnalysis\\Sales_Data\\"+file)
    all_data = pd.concat([all_data,df])
    all_data.head()
```