# Python list directory, subdirectory, and files

Tags: python, file, path

I'm trying to make a script to list all directories, subdirectories, and files in a given directory.

I tried this:

```py
import sys, os

root = "/home/patate/directory/"
path = os.path.join(root, "targetdirectory")

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly. I get all the files, but not their complete paths.

For example, if the directory struct would be:

```
/home/patate/directory/targetdirectory/123/456/789/file.txt
```

It would print:

```
/home/patate/directory/targetdirectory/file.txt
```

I need the first result.

Answer (score 399, accepted):

Use `os.path.join` to concatenate the *directory* and file *name*:

```
import os

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

Note the usage of `path` and not `root` in the concatenation, since using `root` would be incorrect.

---

In Python 3.4, the [pathlib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/pathlib.html) module was added for easier path manipulations. So the equivalent to `os.path.join` would be:

```
pathlib.PurePath(path, name)
```

The advantage of `pathlib` is that you can use a variety of useful methods on paths. If you use the concrete `Path` variant you can also do actual OS calls through them, like changing into a directory, deleting the path, opening the file it points to and much more.

Comment: this is the one and only useful answer for the many questions that have been asked concerning "how to get all files recursively in python".

Comment: comprehension list: all_files = [os.path.join(path, name) for name in files for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder)]

Comment: In Python3 use parenthesis for print function `print(os.path.join(path, name))`

Comment: `os.walk(root)` would inspect all contents of `root`. if you want to look within the provided directory as said in the original question you should use `os.walk(path)`

Answer (score 81):

Just in case... Getting all files in the directory and subdirectories matching some pattern (*.py for example):

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

root = '/some/directory'
pattern = "*.py"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, pattern):
            print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

Comment: In Python3 use parenthesis for print function `print(os.path.join(path, name))`. You can also use `print(pathlib.PurePath(path, name))`.

Comment: same check could be done with simple string .endswith() method ;)
fnmatch uses unix-shell wildcards: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html

Comment: if all you need is to check the file extension, personally I'd prefer using `if name.endswith(".py"):` instead of importing a module.

Answer (score 13):

### Here is a one-liner:

```
import os

[val for sublist in [[os.path.join(i[0], j) for j in i[2]] for i in os.walk('./')] for val in sublist]
# Meta comment to ease selecting text
```

The outer most `val for sublist in ...` loop flattens the list to be one dimensional. The `j` loop collects a list of every file basename and joins it to the current path. Finally, the `i` loop iterates over all directories and sub directories.

This example uses the hard-coded path `./` in the [`os.walk(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) call, you can supplement any path string you like.

*Note: [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) and/or [`os.path.expandvars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) can be used for paths strings like `~/`*

### Extending this example:

It’s easy to add in file basename tests and directoryname tests.

For example, testing for `*.jpg` files:

```
... for j in i[2] if j.endswith('.jpg')] ...
```

Additionally, excluding the `.git` directory:

```
... for i in os.walk('./') if '.git' not in i[0].split('/')]
```

Comment: It does work, but to excluve .git directoy you need to check if '.git' is NOT into the path.

Comment: Yep. Should be if '.git' not in i[0].split('/')]

Comment: I would recommend `os.walk` over a manual dirlisting loop, generators are great, go use them.

Answer (score 13):

Another option would be using the [**glob**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) module from the standard library:

```
import glob

path = "/home/patate/directory/targetdirectory/**"

for path in glob.glob(path, recursive=True):
    print(path)
```

If you need an iterator you can use [**iglob**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) as an alternative:

```
for file in glob.iglob(my_path, recursive=True):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit simpler one-liner:

```py
import os
from itertools import product, chain

chain.from_iterable([[os.sep.join(w) for w in product([i[0]], i[2])] for i in os.walk(dir)])
```

Comment: how do I list each file ?

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at this sample I made. It uses the *os.path.walk* function which is deprecated beware. It uses a list to store all the filepaths.

```
root = "Your root directory"
ex = ".txt"
where_to = "Wherever you wanna write your file to"

def fileWalker(ext, dirname, names):
    '''
    checks files in names'''
    pat = "*" + ext[0]
    for f in names:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, pat):
            ext[1].append(os.path.join(dirname, f))


def writeTo(fList):

    with open(where_to, "w") as f:
        for di_r in fList:
            f.write(di_r + "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    li = []
    os.path.walk(root, fileWalker, [ex, li])

    writeTo(li)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since every example here is just using `walk` (with `join`), I'd like to show a nice example and comparison with `listdir`:

```
import os, time

def listFiles1(root): # listdir
    allFiles = []; walk = [root]
    while walk:
        folder = walk.pop(0)+"/"; items = os.listdir(folder) # items = folders + files
        for i in items: i=folder+i; (walk if os.path.isdir(i) else allFiles).append(i)
    return allFiles

def listFiles2(root): # listdir/join (takes ~1.4x as long) (and uses '\\' instead)
    allFiles = []; walk = [root]
    while walk:
        folder = walk.pop(0); items = os.listdir(folder) # items = folders + files
        for i in items: i=os.path.join(folder,i); (walk if os.path.isdir(i) else allFiles).append(i)
    return allFiles

def listFiles3(root): # walk (takes ~1.5x as long)
    allFiles = []
    for folder, folders, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files: allFiles+=[folder.replace("\\","/")+"/"+file] # folder+"\\"+file still ~1.5x
    return allFiles

def listFiles4(root): # walk/join (takes ~1.6x as long) (and uses '\\' instead)
    allFiles = []
    for folder, folders, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files: allFiles+=[os.path.join(folder,file)]
    return allFiles


for i in range(100): files = listFiles1("src") # warm up

start = time.time()
for i in range(100): files = listFiles1("src") # listdir
print("Time taken: %.2fs"%(time.time()-start)) # 0.28s

start = time.time()
for i in range(100): files = listFiles2("src") # listdir and join
print("Time taken: %.2fs"%(time.time()-start)) # 0.38s

start = time.time()
for i in range(100): files = listFiles3("src") # walk
print("Time taken: %.2fs"%(time.time()-start)) # 0.42s

start = time.time()
for i in range(100): files = listFiles4("src") # walk and join
print("Time taken: %.2fs"%(time.time()-start)) # 0.47s
```

So as you can see for yourself, the `listdir` version is much more efficient. (and that `join` is slow)

Answer (score 3):

Using any supported Python version (3.4+), you should use [`pathlib.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to recursively list the contents of the current directory and all subdirectories:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def generate_all_files(root: Path, only_files: bool = True):
    for p in root.rglob("*"):
        if only_files and not p.is_file():
            continue
        yield p


for p in generate_all_files(Path("."), only_files=False):
    print(p)
```

If you want something copy-pasteable:

### Example

Folder structure:

```
$ tree . -a
.
├── a.txt
├── bar
├── b.py
├── collect.py
├── empty
├── foo
│   └── bar.bz.gz2
├── .hidden
│   └── secrect-file
└── martin
    └── thoma
        └── cv.pdf
```

gives:

```
$ python collect.py
bar
empty
.hidden
collect.py
a.txt
b.py
martin
foo
.hidden/secrect-file
martin/thoma
martin/thoma/cv.pdf
foo/bar.bz.gz2
```

Comment: Where was this tested? For example, the name of the executable is `python3` in later versions of [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29).

Comment: I have no clue what you refer to.

Comment: ***What operating system was this tested on?*** For instance, this will *not* work on some versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04 and sometimes Mac. Why do you think this would not work on Ubuntu?

Comment: Because they removed the executable "python" in some versions of Ubuntu (with only the executable "python3" being available (by default)). E.g., from [this](https://geniusgeeks.com/uninstall-python-ubuntu/): *"From the launch of Ubuntu 22.04, you will only get Python 3.8 installed, and they are no longer shipping with Python2"*. Though I think it started in Ubuntu 18.04 already.

Comment: [Sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLkYmDqJB_g&t=13s): Invoking "python" from the command line on Ubuntu 20.04 (presumably the default installation) results in: *"`Command 'python' not found, did you mean: command 'python3' from deb python3`*

Comment: Are you seriously complaining that the command on your machine is called `python3` instead of `python`?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with me. I am just the messenger. There is a different behaviour on my machine, probably because of a different (installation) configuration, but the error "`Command 'python' not found`"  is well known in the Ubuntu world (it was a conscious decision by Canonical (the company), not an accident or bug). On behalf on ***future readers***, I am complaining about in the ***inaccuracy*** of your answer (in its current state). I have provided evidence that it will not work in the some (default) installations of Ubuntu. It is up to you if you want to correct it or not.

Comment: On some system its python, python3, python3.11, python311, python.exe, python3.exe, python3.11.exe, anaconda, ... It is unreasonable to list this all. If people have difficulties executing python at all, they should ask another question. If I go there, then the next person might ask for hints how to install Python. The next one asks how to install the OS. For this question, I assume the person knows how to execute python on their machine. The answer is not inaccurate. It just assumes very basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

And this is how you list it in case you want to list the files on [SharePoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharePoint). Your path will probably start after the "\teams\" part.

```
import os

root = r"\\mycompany.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\teams\MyFolder\Policies and Procedures\Deal Docs\My Deals"
list = [os.path.join(path, name) for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root) for name in files]
print(list)
```

Comment: What is special about SharePoint? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Most companies use SharePoint to store files.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an addition. With this, you can get the data into CSV format:

```
import sys, os

try:
    import pandas as pd
except:
    os.system("pip3 install pandas")

root = "/home/kiran/Downloads/MainFolder" # It may have many subfolders and files inside
lst = []
from fnmatch import fnmatch
pattern = "*.csv"      # I want to get only csv files
pattern = "*.*"        # Note: Use this pattern to get all types of files and folders
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, pattern):
            lst.append((os.path.join(path, name)))
df = pd.DataFrame({"filePaths":lst})
df.to_csv("filepaths.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple solution would be to run a couple of sub process calls to export the files into CSV format:

```
import subprocess

# Global variables for directory being mapped

location = '.' # Enter the path here.
pattern = '*.py' # Use this if you want to only return certain filetypes
rootDir = location.rpartition('/')[-1]
outputFile = rootDir + '_directory_contents.csv'

# Find the requested data and export to CSV, specifying a pattern if needed.
find_cmd = 'find ' + location + ' -name ' + pattern +  ' -fprintf ' + outputFile + '  "%Y%M,%n,%u,%g,%s,%A+,%P\n"'
subprocess.call(find_cmd, shell=True)
```

That command produces comma-separated values that can be easily analyzed in Excel.

```
f-rwxrwxrwx,1,cathy,cathy,2642,2021-06-01+00:22:00.2970880000,content-audit.py
```

The resulting CSV file doesn't have a header row, but you can use a second command to add them.

```
# Add headers to the CSV
headers_cmd = 'sed -i.bak 1i"Permissions,Links,Owner,Group,Size,ModifiedTime,FilePath" ' + outputFile
subprocess.call(headers_cmd, shell=True)
```

Depending on how much data you get back, you can massage it further using [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29). Here are some things I found useful, especially if you're dealing with many levels of directories to look through.

Add these to your imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Then add this to your code:

```
# Create DataFrame from the CSV file created above.
df = pd.read_csv(outputFile)

# Format columns
# Get the filename and file extension from the filepath
df['FileName'] = df['FilePath'].str.rsplit("/", 1).str[-1]
df['FileExt'] = df['FileName'].str.rsplit('.', 1).str[1]

# Get the full path to the files. If the path doesn't include a "/" it's the root directory
df['FullPath'] = df["FilePath"].str.rsplit("/", 1).str[0]
df['FullPath'] = np.where(df['FullPath'].str.contains("/"), df['FullPath'], rootDir)

# Split the path into columns for the parent directory and its children
df['ParentDir'] = df['FullPath'].str.split("/", 1).str[0]
df['SubDirs'] = df['FullPath'].str.split("/", 1).str[1]
# Account for NaN returns, indicates the path is the root directory
df['SubDirs'] = np.where(df.SubDirs.str.contains('NaN'), '', df.SubDirs)

# Determine if the item is a directory or file.
df['Type'] = np.where(df['Permissions'].str.startswith('d'), 'Dir', 'File')

# Split the time stamp into date and time columns
df[['ModifiedDate', 'Time']] = df.ModifiedTime.str.rsplit('+', 1, expand=True)
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.split('.').str[0]

# Show only files, output includes paths so you don't necessarily need to display the individual directories.
df = df[df['Type'].str.contains('File')]

# Set columns to show and their order.
df = df[['FileName', 'ParentDir', 'SubDirs', 'FullPath', 'DocType', 'ModifiedDate', 'Time', 'Size']]

filesize = [] # Create an empty list to store file sizes to convert them to something more readable.

# Go through the items and convert the filesize from bytes to something more readable.
for items in df['Size'].items():
    filesize.append(convert_bytes(items[1]))
    df['Size'] = filesize

# Send the data to an Excel workbook with sheets by parent directory
with pd.ExcelWriter("scripts_directory_contents.xlsx") as writer:
    for directory, data in df.groupby('ParentDir'):
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = directory, index=False)


# To convert sizes to be more human readable
def convert_bytes(size):
    for x in ['b', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T']:
        if size < 1024:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (size, x)
        size /= 1024

    return size
```