# How to get a list of all files in directory using python.

Tags: python, notepad++

I am using the python plugin  for notepad ++ and need to be able to get a printout of all the files in a directory.  Basically I need to run something like dir in command prompt.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean [`os.listdir('.')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)?

Comment: If by "a printout", you mean something formatted, and with a bunch of additional columns, etc., just like `dir`, then you'll need to use `os.stat` on each one and format the columns yourself—or, of course, you can use `subprocess.check_output` to just run the command prompt's `dir` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) function to get a list of the files in a directory.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's how to put all the files in a directory and in all its sub-directories in a list, print out the list.

Note: How to 'walk' was found here:

[concatenate the directory and file name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909998/5082676)

```
# Task: Get a printout of all the files in a directory.

import os

# The directory that we are interested in
myPath = "/users/george/documents/"

# All the file paths will be stored in this list
filesList= []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(myPath):
    for name in files:
        filesList.append(os.path.join(path, name))

for i in filesList:
    print (str(i))
```