# os.system does not write the result to output file

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.system

I am writing this piece of code :

```
import os
os.system("start /wait cmd /c dir/s *.exe > Allexe1.txt")
```

What it is supposed to do is to get all exe files and write the result on to the file. But I get an empty file .

Note: I have tried the subprocess for the same and I always get the error Error[2] : file not found
I am using Windows 7 , python2.7

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Do you really have `dir/s` with no space?

Comment: Yes John, That is the command which worked in cmd when I tested. I am trying to embed that in python os.system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it your way with this alteration as `start /wait cmd /c` isn't required to execute a command via `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system("dir/s *.exe > Allexe1.txt")
```

However this isn't portable code if you were going to move it to a non windows platform.

If you wish to do it in a more portable fashion I recommend you read this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909975/python-list-directory-subdirectory-and-files)

```
import sys,os

root = "/home/patate/directory/"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        # filter for files with an exe extension here
        print os.path.join(path, name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not enumerate files in Python this way.  Instead, use the included `glob` module:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('*.exe'):
    print filename
```

Or since you seem to want all subdirectories, use `os.walk()` combined with `fnmatch` as mentioned in the `glob` docs.  In any case you should not shell out for this.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 import os

 result = os.popen("start /wait cmd /c dir/s *.exe > Allexe1.txt").read()
 if result is not None:
     #this is your object with all your results
     #you can write to a file
     with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
         f.write(result)
 #you can also print the result to console.
     print result
 else:
     print "Command returned nothing"
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your command but make sure your command is correct

Comment: The command would have exclude the problematic  `start /wait cmd /c` and remove the redirection `> Allexe1.txt` so that there is output to capture.