# How do I get path name, subdirectory name, and list of files in order?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, path

I have been trying my hand at this for a while and I am afraid this will get marked as a duplicate, even though I feel this is not a duplicate to [Python list directory, subdirectory, and files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909975/python-list-directory-subdirectory-and-files). This solution prints it out to the format of `path/subdirectory/files`. But that is not what I need.

Consider the following structure of my directory:

```
Root

 - Directory1
    - Files
 - Directory2
    - Files
 - Directory3
    - Subdirectory
        - Sub-subdirectory1
            - Files
        - Sub-subdirectory2
            - Files
        - Sub-subdirectory3
            - Files
 - Directory4
    - Files
```

For my program, I need the name of the path, which isn’t difficult. However, I also need the name of the subdirectory, which I can do with `for name in subdirs`, however, I cannot get the name of the files within the subdirectory. This is what I have tried:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for dirname in subdirs:
        print dirname
        for filename in os.listdir(path + ‘\\’ + dirname):
            print filename
```

This works until I hit a subdirectory, where it then treats the file names as the subdirectory names. This becomes a problem in my program as it causes it to crash and I am taking information out of the files and converting them into XML files. And I need the directory name in order to properly name the file, and give it the appropriate header.

I want the following output:

```
 - Directory1
    - Files
 - Directory2
    - Files
 - Sub-subdirectory1
    - Files
 - Sub-subdirectory2
    - Files
 - Sub-subdirectory3
    - Files
 - Directory3
    - Files
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print only directories that have files:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    if files:
        print os.path.basename(path)
        for filename in files:
            print '  ' + filename  # spaces are just for indent
```

If you need empty directories too, remove `if files`.