# Making OS File crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm hoping to start a python program that crawls all the folders in my operating system so that I can find all the images and then place them all into a folder (e.g an_image.png). I was wondering if that would be possible, and if so then what module should I import?

Comment: Note that questions are expected to be about a specific problem in code you already wrote, and that questions requesting for a suggested library are explicitly off-topic (see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909975/python-list-directory-subdirectory-and-files):

```
def get_filepaths(directory):
    """
    This function will generate the file names in a directory 
    tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each 
    directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), 
    it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
    """
    file_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.

    # Walk the tree.
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.

    return file_paths  # Self-explanatory.

files = get_filepaths('/')
img_ext = ['png']
image_files = [*filter(lambda x: x.split('.') in img_ext, files)]
```

You can put the extenstion you want in `img_ext` and change the root. I haven't run the code but I expect it will take a very long time since you are going to pass by all your files

Comment: Thank you, I'll make sure to try it out tomorrow

Comment: If the question boiled down to "how do I use os.walk()?", the correct approach would have been to close it as duplicate. See the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before" in the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).