# Render Folder Structure on webpage with Django

Tags: html, django

I have a root folder, containing other folders and XML-files. I would like to show the folder contents just like in windows-explorer on my webpage. For example:

```
folder_1
    txt_file_1
    txt_file_2
folder_2 
    folder_3
        txt_file_3
```

How can I render the directory in this way?

Comment: You can get help from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909998/6427186

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case that I was able to solve by recursively including a template.

In my main template I start the recursion: `{% include "myapp/tree.html" with children=list_of_objects %}`

In the `tree.html` file, the actual recursion occurs:

`{% for child in children %}`

`{% include "myapp/tree.html" with children=list_of_objects %}`

`{% endfor %}`

You would still need to return a list/dictionary of directories from your view (or possibly [create a custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) to handle it).