# How do I concatenate multiple CSV files row-wise using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataset of about 10 CSV files. I want to combine those files row-wise into a single CSV file.

What I tried:

```
import csv
fout = open("claaassA.csv","a")
# first file:
writer = csv.writer(fout)
for line in open("a01.ihr.60.ann.csv"):
     print line
     writer.writerow(line)
# now the rest:    
for num in range(2, 10):
    print num
    f = open("a0"+str(num)+".ihr.60.ann.csv")
#f.next() # skip the header
for line in f:
     print line
     writer.writerow(line)
#f.close() # not really needed
fout.close()
```

Comment: Do your CSV files have the same column names and orders?

Comment: How about this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-to-merge-200-csv-files-in-python

Comment: post some csv data will be helpful

Comment: @RemyaCV, I tried using that code, but it doesnt help

Answer (score 3):

Definitively need more details in the question (ideally examples of the inputs and expected output).

Given the little information provided, I will assume that you know that all files are valid CSV and they all have the same number or lines (rows). I'll also assume that memory is not a concern (i.e. they are "small" files that fit together in memory). Furthermore, I assume that line endings are new line (`\n`).

**If all these assumptions are valid**, then you can do something like this:

```
input_files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']
output_file = 'output.csv'

output = None
for infile in input_files:
    with open(infile, 'r') as fh:
        if output:
            for i, l in enumerate(fh.readlines()):
                output[i] = "{},{}".format(output[i].rstrip('\n'), l)
        else:
            output = fh.readlines()

with open(output_file, 'w') as fh:
    for line in output:
        fh.write(line)
```

There are probably more efficient ways, but this is a quick and dirty way to achieve what I think you are asking for.

---

The previous answer implicitly assumes we *need* to do this in python. If bash is an option then you could use the `paste` command. For example:

```
paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fully why you use the library `csv`. Actually, it's enough to fill the output file with the lines from given files (it they have the same columns' manes and orders).

```
input_path_list = [
    "a01.ihr.60.ann.csv",
    "a02.ihr.60.ann.csv",
    "a03.ihr.60.ann.csv",
    "a04.ihr.60.ann.csv",
    "a05.ihr.60.ann.csv",
    "a06.ihr.60.ann.csv",
    "a07.ihr.60.ann.csv",
    "a08.ihr.60.ann.csv",
    "a09.ihr.60.ann.csv",
]
output_path = "claaassA.csv"

with open(output_path, "w") as fout:
    header_written = False

    for intput_path in input_path_list:
        with open(intput_path) as fin:
            header = fin.next()

            # it adds the header at the beginning and skips other headers
            if not header_written:
                fout.write(header)
                header_written = True

            # it adds all rows
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line)
```