# Merge csv files using python without repeating header

Tags: python, csv, split

I am trying to do this ,

```
import glob

interesting_files = glob.glob("/home/tcs/PYTHONMAP/test1/*.csv") 

header_saved = False
with open('/home/tcs/PYTHONMAP/output.csv','wb') as fout:
    for filename in interesting_files:
        with open(filename) as fin:
            header =  next(fin)
            if not header_saved:
                fout.write(header)
                header_saved = True
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line)
```

and getting

```
File "/home/tcs/.config/spyder-py3/temp.py", line 11, in <module>
    fout.write(header)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I don't know much about python please help
Also i want to know how to split 1 big csv into multiple csv with same header.

Comment: Take a look at Pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-to-merge-200-csv-files-in-python

Comment: You are opening the `fout` file as binary by specifying `'wb'`. I think it should work if you specify `'w'` instead, for writing strings. You might also want to take a look at [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot i did with system command also, can you describe how do we split large csv file into small size but header should be present in each split, Thanks in advance

Comment: sed 2d *.csv > /a2.csv . command is able to concat the same without python,

Comment: @ShubhamChauhan it can't work It will with repeat header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import glob
import csv
interesting_files = glob.glob("/home/tcs/PYTHONMAP/test1/*.csv") 

header_saved = False
with open('/home/tcs/PYTHONMAP/output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for filename in interesting_files:
        with open(filename) as fin:
            header =  next(fin)
            if not header_saved:
                writer.writerows(header) # you may need to work here. The writerows require an iterable.
                header_saved = True
            writer.writerows(fin.readlines())
```

Answer (score 19):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

interesting_files = glob.glob("/home/tcs/PYTHONMAP/test1/*.csv") 
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, header = 0) for f in interesting_files))
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

To get rid of duplicate rows as well:

```
import pandas as pd

interesting_files = glob.glob("/home/tcs/PYTHONMAP/test1/*.csv") 
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, header = 0) for f in interesting_files))
df_deduplicated = df.drop_duplicates()
df_deduplicated.to_csv("output.csv")
```

This will not get rid of duplicates as the dataframe is created, but after. So a dataframe gets created by concatenating all of the files. Then it is de-duplicated. The final dataframe can then be saved to csv.

Comment: is there any way I can also remove duplicates simultaneously?

Comment: @Rahul do you mean duplicate rows? I've updated my answer to include a way to remove duplicate rows, hope this helps! :)

Comment: how can this be done though if the size of your data won't fit into memory? with this approach, `df` can become greater in size than the machines RAM is capable of holding.