# Python Pandas - speed up csv join

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have an optimization problem. I need to join some csv (all have the same structure) in a unique csv.

The structure of my folders is following a temporal order: year/month/day/hour_file_identifier.csv. Thus 16y*365d*24h = 140160 files. This is the maximum number of files I can have as a result. Each folder indexed by day can have an arbitrary number of files (that I am generating with a python script too). As the number of files will exceed the maximum allowed for an ext4 filesystem every N iteration I need to join all the files in hour_indexed files, to not encounter this problem.

So, the input of what I call `join_routine` is the folders indexed by time, as example:

```
2001/9/3/
2002/8/4/
```

Each of these folders can contain a varibale number of files as:

```
2001/9/3/
    1-01.csv
    1-02.csv
    2-01.csv
2002/8/4/
    1-01.csv
    2-01.csv
    3-01.csv
    3-01.csv
```

The results of the `join_routine` should be:

```
2001/9/3/
    1-joined.csv
    2-joined.csv
2002/8/4/
    1-joined.csv
    2-joined.csv
    3-joined.csv
```

To do that I develop the following code:

```
def join_routine():
#    print('JOIN ROUTINE')
    directory_list = [x.replace('\\','/') for x in glob.glob('data/csv/plays/*/*/*/')]

    for directory in directory_list:
        for hour in range(0,13):
            file_list = [x.replace('\\','/') for x in glob.glob(directory+ str(hour) +'-*.csv')]
            if len(file_list) > 0:
                df = read_csv_list(file_list)
                df.to_csv(directory+str(hour)+'-joined.csv', index = False)
                for file in [ x for x in file_list if x not in directory+str(hour)+'-joined.csv']:
                    os.remove(file)

def read_csv_list(file_list):
    df_list = []
#    with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=len(file_list)) as bar:
#        i = 0
    for file in file_list:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df_list.append(df)
#            i = i + 1
#            bar.update(i)

    return pd.concat(df_list, axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
```

The `join_routine` function handles the join of each folder in a single process. I am wondering if there is a better and more important, a quicker way of doing that. The `join_routine` is taking more than 10X of the file creation (that is done on a parallel process pool of 16 workers). I need to do the `join_routine` 21 times and is gonna take more than 1 week at this pace, which is not feasible.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use pandas!

Experiment 1: Read file and append to another line by line 
(code adopted from [how to merge 200 csv files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-to-merge-200-csv-files-in-python)):

```
import time

#%%
start1 = time.time()
fout=open("out.csv","a")
# first file:
for line in open("file.csv"):
    fout.write(line)
# now the rest:    
for num in range(2,201):
    f = open("file.csv")
    f.__next__() # skip the header
    for line in f:
         fout.write(line)
    f.close() # not really needed
fout.close()
end1 = time.time()
print(end1-start1) #0.3000311851501465
```

Experiment 2(Using pandas to read, concat, and write csv file):

```
import time
import pandas as pd
start2 = time.time()
df_list = []
for i in range(200):
    df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
    df_list.append(df)
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
df.to_csv('out2.csv', index = False)
end2 = time.time()
print(end2-start2) #3.0119707584381104
```

Comment: Thank you, do you think that moving to a process pool will help too? Or the I/O will put everything on sleep?

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file.