# Reading multiple CSV files and merge Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am reading specific csv files names based on their name with this code:

```
csv_names = [s for s in files_csv if "drive" in s]
```

output:

```
['drive_1.csv',
 'drive_2.csv',
 'drive_3.csv',
 'drive_4.csv']
```

How can i merge those files easy?

I am know doing this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_names[0], sep=';', header=None) 
df1 = pd.read_csv(csv_names[1], sep=';', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv_names[2], sep=';', header=None)
df3 = pd.read_csv(csv_names[3], sep=';', header=None)
```

I don't want to read them one by one. And then merge them. I hope someone has a great idea.

Comment: Do you want to merge the files or append them? I have a feeling you want to append the files together. If so, then `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', header=None) for file in csv_names])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to merge 200 csv files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-to-merge-200-csv-files-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` and a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv_name, sep=';', header=None) for csv_name in csv_names])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
for csv in csv_name:
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', header=None)])
df.to_csv('Merged_Data_Frame.csv', index=False)
```

Hope this helps. This will merge and save them to csv for later use.